# Compare non-contiguous Ranges values and count values occurrence

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare values from non-contiguous ranges and then write down the number of the same value occurrence

[image]

I used this code from last post but it compares only values from the same range

```
Sub tbl()

  Dim Range1 As Range
  Dim Range2 As Variant
  Dim range3() As Variant, j As Long

      Set Range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
      Range2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")

      ReDim range3(1 To UBound(Range2, 1), 1 To 1)


         For j = 1 To UBound(Range2, 1)
          range3(j,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, 
            Range2(j,1))
         Next j

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(UBound(range3), 1).Value = 
            range3


       End Sub
```

Comment: Range1 = Weekend / Range1= normal days of the week and I have another range for holydays

Comment: could use Union to combine the ranges (e.g. the two for range 1) then loop over the .Areas of that adding to a dictionary the cell.value (as key), 1 (as value). If already in dictionary (dict.Exists..) add 1 to existing value for that key.

Comment: Range1 = Weekend / Range2= normal days of the week and I have another range for holydays

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
Function COUNT_THIS_VALUE(ByRef CountThis As Range, ByRef InthisRange As Range) As Double

Dim AddressArray() As String
Dim i As Double
AddressArray = Split(InthisRange.Address(False, False), ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(AddressArray) Step 1
    COUNT_THIS_VALUE = COUNT_THIS_VALUE + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(AddressArray(i)), CountThis.Value)
Next i
End Function
```

First argument of function is WHAT YOU WANT TO COUNT. It must be a single cell. Second argument of the function is in what range you want to search.

I did a simple table with random values between 1 and 10. Yellow rows are my Range1 and white rows are my Range2. I counted all numbers from 1 to 10 in each range and did a table. Take a look at the image to understand better.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but you still didn't get what i really want to achieve. First I have two tables let's call them tableOne and tableTwo. tableOne is for workers guard that is related to dates for example worker one have a guard in 01.01.2018 and another guard on 03.01.2018 and another guard on 07.01.2018 according to this worker one have 3 guards in different dates . for that in tableTwo I have the list of workers and three column one for guard at weekend , one for guard at holydays and another column for guard at normal days.

Comment: I want to count each worker's guard and write the number of guards in tableTwo according to dates weekend holiday normal days. Is it clear

Comment: Sorry, but your question was "I am trying to compare values from non-contiguous ranges and then write down the number of the same value occurrence" and that's what I answered. It's the first time you say something about the guard, and 2 tables and rest of stuff. That explains why "I did not get it". Next time you want to ask something, please, put all information you have, explain all slowly and with details and people "will get it"

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake. I hope to help me

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake. I hope to help me

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)  and see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)